# Compiling C++ for OSX from Windows

Tags: c++, macos, cross-platform, visual-studio-2012

I have a small console based, standards compliant, C++ program that I developed in Visual Studio on Windows. Since it is in standard C++, is all I need to do is compile it for OSX? or am I being overly optimistic?

I am looking for the easiest and most straightforward way to do this. Is it possible to do from Visual Studio 2012 Professional? If necessary I have access to a Mac. However, since my dev platform is Windows, it would be nice if I could do it from here.

I'm not experienced with mac development at all. When you compile an application for OSX, what do you get instead of a .exe?

Comment: There will probably be some work, since no compiler is good at telling you if your program is well defined.  And VC++ isn't a great tool to test if your program is standards-compliant.  You won't have to rewrite it, but you'll be making improvements here and there.

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253768/porting-c-code-from-windows-to-the-mac?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would get an OSX system (a VM is fine), install XCode and then compile your code using that. Should be trivial if your C++ code is written in a cross platform way.

Comment: Running OSX in a VM that is not hosted on another OSX system is a license violation. Not the best way to start development for a new target.

Comment: I'll see if I can go get my hands on a system with XCode. Thanks

Comment: @Kyryx you don't necessarily need XCode. You could build your code on any *nix platform using `g++`, `gnu make` together with CMake or scons, then trivially port to OSX.

Comment: Quick google of "macos vm online" and you will find for a relatively low monthly price you can get remote access to a Mac VM for development. There are at least 5 providers.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind installing MinGW or Cygwin to your Windows machine, you can build a Windows to OS X cross-toolchain as per the instructions here: https://github.com/Tatsh/xchain