# How to compile C++ for Mac OS X using Visual Studio on Windows and CMake

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio, cmake, cross-compiling

[I read that `Visual Studio` now supports cross-platform development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341443/3764804). I'm using `CMake` to compile for `Windows` and `Ubuntu` (using `WSL`) so far. However there doesn't seem to be any information on how to actually accomplish the cross-compilation using `Visual Studio` to target `Mac OS X`. Is it doable with the `CMakeSettings.json`? According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/cmake-tools-for-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017) article, you can choose `Linux-Debug` and `Linux-Release` as `configurationType` but in `Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise` the `Linux` options aren't even available for me, neither is `Mac OS X`.

I might just setup a virtual machine as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12544524/3764804) post which seems to be the most convenient solution to get the job done.

Comment: to compile for MacOS you'll need xcode toolset, BUT Apple forbide the use of it on platform other than MacOS i.e. you can't cross compile for MacOS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can't.

[I ended up installing a virtual machine with `Mac OS X`](https://www.cybernog.com/2018/10/MacOS-Mojave-VMware.html) and successfully compiled my code inside it using shared folders to make my `Windows` host source code available to the guest. This is certainly more reliable and sane to do than [some hacky cross-compilation project](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross). The latter still doesn't guarantee that the code will successfully run and not unexpectedly crash on the cross-compilation target operating system.

---

Alternatively, if you can get your hands on an (old) Macbook or so you can use that and enable network sharing to your main machine (e.g. a Windows PC). This way you can grab freshly compiled binaries directly from your Macbook using Windows and you're set with compiling your macOS builds.