# How to make executables work on OSX Mavericks

Tags: c, executable, osx-mavericks

I've been working on a school project, in C, and I plan to distribute it to students and anyone interested...
The problem here is the executable file won't run on OS X Mavericks...
is there any way they can do this ***without***  getting a simulator, or an application like wine.

( Like how you have to install Visual C/C++ & DirectX for games? )

Comment: This is not very clear. Which operating system do you run the application on when you develop it?

Comment: DirectX doesn't exist outside the Windows world. If you want to run Windows programs on a non-Windows system, you need an emulator or virtual environment.

Comment: Great last line... So why *don't* you need "a simulator or wine" to run "Visual C/DirectX [games]" on OSX?

Answer (score 2):

Since C compiled code is not platform agnostic like Java, you need to compile the code for the target platform(s) you are interested in.

If you have access to OSX Mavericks, you can compile on that OS to get the executable and test. (Copy your C source code to the mac OS, or better use a source control system like git)

If you do not have access to OSX, you can look up how to build/use cross compiler. (Links to related SO questions below that address this)

The effort needed for cross-compile and test would likely be non-trivial, so if you can get access to OSX that will be your best bet.

In either case, you will have to make sure the code written is platform-agnostic.

---

Several similar questions on stack overflow that talk about the various cross compiling options:

[Way Cross Compile C/C++ code to run on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031453/way-cross-compile-c-c-code-to-run-on-windows-linux-and-mac-os)

[How to Compile for OS X in Linux or Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693952/how-to-compile-for-os-x-in-linux-or-windows)

[Porting C++ code from Windows to the Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253768/porting-c-code-from-windows-to-the-mac?rq=1)

---